# Remove grouping variable when using RowGroup extension in DT R package

Tags: r, dt

I'm trying to use the `RowGroup` extension in the `DT` package. I'm able to create the row groups but I now want to remove that grouping variable as a column in the table (it's redundant having it in two places).

In this reproducible example I'm grouping by `cyl` but `cyl` also appears as a column. Obviously if I remove it from the data I can't group anymore.

```
library(DT)

data_to_tabulate <- head(mtcars[order(mtcars$cyl), ])

datatable(
  data_to_tabulate,
  extensions = 'RowGroup',
  options = list(rowGroup = list(dataSrc = 2)),
  selection = 'none'
)
```

Need to remove the red bordered column.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `columnDefs` option to hide a column by setting `visible=FALSE`. For you example the following code hides the second column:

```
library(DT)

data_to_tabulate <- head(mtcars[order(mtcars$cyl), ])

datatable(
  data_to_tabulate,
  extensions = "RowGroup",
  options = list(
    rowGroup = list(dataSrc = 2),
    columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(2)))
  ),
  selection = "none"
)
```

[image]